# How to change Device Language and Country (Locale) in Calabash-Android

Tags: android, automation, calabash-android

I would like to change **Device** country & language using calabash (Android & iOS), I could not find in official docs: calabashapi.xamarin.com/android/

I have seen `set_gps_coordinates_from_location` it is not helpful for me.

Comment: After getting country compare with string file using loop and this and set country name code language

Answer (score 2):

public class GetCityCountry extends AsyncTask {
            ProgressDialog proDialog;

```
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            proDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            proDialog.setCancelable(false);
            //proDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //  proDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(getActivity(),Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> adddddd = coder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(latitude_from),Double.parseDouble(longitude_from),1);
                if (adddddd.size() > 0) {
                    myCity = adddddd.get(0).getLocality();
                    MyCountry = adddddd.get(0).getCountryName();


                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            proDialog.dismiss();
            Utils.SetPreferences(getActivity(),My_Tags.MY_COUNTRY,MyCountry);
            Utils.SetPreferences(getActivity(),My_Tags.CURRENT_CITY, myCity);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
```

put In String folder in android  /////////////////////

English, US (en_US)               1.1
German, Germany (de_DE)           1.1
Chinese, PRC (zh_CN)              1.5
Chinese, Taiwan (zh_TW)           1.5
Czech, Czech Republic (cs_CZ)     1.5
Dutch, Belgium (nl_BE)            1.5
Dutch, Netherlands (nl_NL)        1.5
English, Australia (en_AU)        1.5
English, Britain (en_GB)          1.5
English, Canada (en_CA)           1.5
English, New Zealand (en_NZ)      1.5
English, Singapore(en_SG)         1.5
French, Belgium (fr_BE)           1.5
French, Canada (fr_CA)            1.5
French, France (fr_FR)            1.5
French, Switzerland (fr_CH)       1.5
German, Austria (de_AT)           1.5
German, Liechtenstein (de_LI)     1.5
German, Switzerland (de_CH)       1.5
Italian, Italy (it_IT)            1.5
Italian, Switzerland (it_CH)      1.5
Japanese (ja_JP)                  1.5
Korean (ko_KR)                    1.5
Polish (pl_PL)                    1.5
Russian (ru_RU)                   1.5
Spanish (es_ES)                   1.5
Arabic, Egypt (ar_EG)             2.3
Arabic, Israel (ar_IL)            2.3
Bulgarian, Bulgaria (bg_BG)       2.3
Catalan, Spain (ca_ES)            2.3
Croatian, Croatia (hr_HR)         2.3
Danish, Denmark(da_DK)            2.3
English, India (en_IN)            2.3
English, Ireland (en_IE)          2.3
English, Zimbabwe (en_ZA)         2.3
Finnish, Finland (fi_FI)          2.3
Greek, Greece (el_GR)             2.3
Hebrew, Israel (iw_IL)*           2.3
Hindi, India (hi_IN)              2.3
Hungarian, Hungary (hu_HU)        2.3
Indonesian, Indonesia (in_ID)*    2.3
Latvian, Latvia (lv_LV)           2.3
Lithuanian, Lithuania (lt_LT)     2.3
Norwegian-Bokmol, Norway(nb_NO)   2.3
Portuguese, Brazil (pt_BR)        2.3
Portuguese, Portugal (pt_PT)      2.3
Romanian, Romania (ro_RO)         2.3
Serbian (sr_RS)                   2.3
Slovak, Slovakia (sk_SK)          2.3
Slovenian, Slovenia (sl_SI)       2.3
Spanish, US (es_US)               2.3
Swedish, Sweden (sv_SE)           2.3
Tagalog, Philippines (tl_PH)      2.3
Thai, Thailand (th_TH)            2.3
Turkish, Turkey (tr_TR)           2.3
Ukrainian, Ukraine (uk_UA)        2.3
Vietnamese, Vietnam (vi_VN)       2.3

Comment: After getting country compare with string file using loop and this and set country name code language

Comment: I need to change programmatically in Calabash-Android which is based on Ruby Language. Your code seems to be Java code. can you please elaborate your answer.